# Django logger - tracebacks not propagating

Tags: python, django, logging

I replaced all loggers by a catch-all logger in my logging conf in django settings, like:

```
'loggers': {
    '': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'DEBUG'
    }
}
```

So I guessed the result would be exactly the same as having the `'django'` logger with the same settings. But I'm not seeing the stack trace of errors that are raised (notably on requets), with the above "catch-all" configuration.

Whereas it prints ok again if I add:

```
'django': {
    'handlers': ['null'],
    'propagate': True
},
```

It seems that the `'django'` logger somehow does the job of adding the traceback to the log?

But anyway what's the reason things behave like that? Why is it that things change when adding the second code snippet? Seems to me there is a part of the story I don't know.

(django 1.5)

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can see for this happening is that the `propagation` attribute is set to `False` on the `django` and/or `django.requests` loggers by default, and your specifying it explicitly overrides this. In Django 1.5, as compared with earlier versions, the configuration specified in your `settings.py` can be merged with Django's default, as explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#configuring-logging).

It's generally better to leave propagation alone unless there are specific reasons for overriding the default value of `True`. Django's own configs sometimes specify `True` explicitly in the configuration, which IMO serves no purpose other than documenting what would be happening anyway.

You would need to show the complete configuration for the specific 1.5 version of Django you're using to nail down the exact reason for the behaviour you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `settings.py` to set a catch-all logger:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'root': {'level': 'DEBUG'}
}
```

Without seeing your full `LOGGING` setting it's not possible to be sure, but here's my guess for what's happening. I'm not convinced that the empty-string-named `''` logger actually works as the root logger; it may do nothing. Additionally, because your settings are not merged with Django's, the 'console' handler won't be defined. *If* that logger was used, I'd expect it to throw an error like `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'level'`. Same with the 'null' handler.

However, when you add that 'django' logger it *does* correspond with the logger Django actually uses and the `propagate` setting takes effect bubbling up to the native root logger, which by default prints to `sys.stderr`. By definition though the root logger catches all things, so you shouldn't have to specifically name a 'django' logger. Again something in your full `LOGGING` setting could be conflicting.